# img onHover & onClick effects for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

The website I'm working on: stipz.50webs.com

*p.s. HOME does nothing for now*

Since I've nailed the onhover and onmouseout part what I want to add is the navigation effects for each div/img to let the end-user know which div is clicked / active

When a certain div is active I want it to change the src and the onmouseout
but that means I have to change the rest of the div/img back to their default ones using 
is it possible to have multiple declarations on multiple div id in a single function?

I might figure out a code if there is a possibility for that to work

currently working on:

```
$('#orgn').click("mouseenter", function() {
$(this).attr('src', 'elements/mp_onhover/origin_on.png');
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
$(this).attr('src', "elements/mp_onhover/origin_off.png");
});
```

edit:
I've tried working on this one again, I think it's really beyond me as a coder.
I made a jsfiddle for it but it's not working properly 
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/stipz/52xxuqm4/1/)
alternative link: http://stipz.50webs.com/div_navigation.html

What I tried was add/remove class onClick for each div

```
$("#div-origin").click( function () { $(this).addClass("ori-active"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("ori-active"); } );
```

Comment: sorry I kind of confused everyone on how I explained my coding problem

what I want is for a navigation link to remain lit when the div is when you clicked it is active

Comment: _“Since I've nailed the onhover and onmouseout part”_ – only if you consider doing something with JavaScript that could be done without it (and even rather easier) with CSS alone, “nailing it” …

Comment: i revamped it to div {;} div:active {;} and div:hover {;} but now I'm stuck with how to replace its background when a specific div is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long code but I've managed to achieve what I wanted for the navigation effect.

See updated live webpage: [HERE](http://stipz.50webs.com/div_navigation.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('.do').hover(
  function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_origin.png)');},
  function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png)');}); 
$('.dp').hover(
  function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_profile.png)');},
  function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png)');}); 
$('.da').hover(
  function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_affil.png)');},
  function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_affil.png)');});
$('.dc').hover(
  function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_combat.png)');},
  function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_combat.png)');});    
$('.do').click(function() 
 {
  $('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_origin.png)');
  $('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png)');
  $('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_affil.png)');
  $('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_combat.png)');
  $('.do').hover(
    function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_origin.png)');},
    function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_origin.png)');}); 
    $('.dp').hover(
    function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_profile.png)');},
    function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png)');}); 
  $('.da').hover(
    function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_affil.png)');},
    function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_affil.png)');});
     $('.dc').hover(
    function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_combat.png)');},
    function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_combat.png)');});     
 });
$('.dp').click(function() 
 {
  $('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png)');
  $('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_profile.png)');
  $('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_affil.png)');
  $('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_combat.png)');
  $('.do').hover(
    function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_origin.png)');},
    function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png)');}); 
    $('.dp').hover(
    function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_profile.png)');},
    function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_profile.png)');}); 
  $('.da').hover(
    function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_affil.png)');},
    function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_affil.png)');});
     $('.dc').hover(
    function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_combat.png)');},
    function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_combat.png)');});     
 });
$('.da').click(function() 
 {
  $('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png)');
  $('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png)');
  $('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_affil.png)');
  $('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_combat.png)');
  $('.do').hover(
    function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_origin.png)');},
    function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png)');}); 
    $('.dp').hover(
    function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_profile.png)');},
    function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png)');}); 
  $('.da').hover(
    function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_affil.png)');},
    function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_affil.png)');});
     $('.dc').hover(
    function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_combat.png)');},
    function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_combat.png)');});     
 });
$('.dc').click(function() 
{
 $('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png)');
 $('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png)');
 $('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_affil.png)');
 $('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_combat.png)');
 $('.do').hover(
   function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_origin.png)');},
   function() {$('.do').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png)');}); 
 $('.dp').hover(
    function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_profile.png)');},
   function() {$('.dp').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png)');}); 
    $('.da').hover(
   function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/on_affil.png)');},
   function() {$('.da').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/nm_affil.png)');});
 $('.dc').hover(
   function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_combat.png)');},
   function() {$('.dc').css('background-image', 'url(elements/mp_onhover/ac_combat.png)');}); 
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with CSS only,see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmwvbw9s/)

basic css and we are game.

```
.link:link{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  background-color:red;
}

.link:hover{
  background-color:green; 
}
.link:visited{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Now i changed `color` in that fiddle because i did not want to take pain in uploading picture to jsfiddle. now you can change the background pic from there, no use of jquery

> PS:- I see you have used `img` inside `a`, i think you can remove `img` and set background image of `a`

Comment: Thank you. I think I can use this with another approach
I made it that way so that I can call 2 javascript functions in one click

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you expect.I only concerned about your two links.look at this code.

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    ul li{
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      display: block;
      color: black;
    
    }
    
    .classOne{
      text-shadow:2px 2px 1px green;
    }
    
    </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CHARACTERS</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- js--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul li a").mouseenter(function(){
          $(this).addClass("classOne");
          });
        $("ul li a").mouseleave(function(){
          $(this).removeClass("classOne");
        });
     });
    </script>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

make changes as your needs.

Comment: I was avoiding on using ul li  since I don't know how to properly incorporate them with divs
This was one of the methods I used during my testing process in highlighting divs 
but not exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: so what do you use, only `<a></a>`, and here, I do not higilight any div here, simply add style to the text

Comment: i think this would be the solution to my problem but having multiple images to add in the active class confuses me.

Comment: what do you mean , multiple images ?I didn't ge it.what do you want to do exactly

Comment: i have divs that uses background-image with the css rules :active and :hover. see here http://www.stipz.50webs.com/div_navigation.html